# how do I deal with run-time dependency conflicts on SBT?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, runtime-error, sbt-assembly

Let't put this in context.

I have a line of code running within a broader program(Spark/Scala)

```
   val dateGroupKVpair: RDD[(String, Iterable[Option[stockPriceInfo]])] =
      stockDataFilteredRDD.keyBy(x =>
        x.get.ticker + "|" + x.get.dateTime.split("@")(0).split("-")(0) //year
           + x.get.dateTime.split("@")(0).split("-")(1) //month
          + x.get.dateTime.split("@")(0).split("-")(2)).groupByKey.sortBy(_._1, false)
```

This line results in the following exception

```
15/10/19 19:33:22 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
Exception in thread "Driver" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:162)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD$
        at Job$.main(Job.scala:55)
        at Job.main(Job.scala)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 7 more
15/10/19 19:33:22 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$1: Invoking sc stop from shutdown hook
```

In my build.sbt file, I have the dependencies for org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD -- the same version I have in jar_home.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0-cdh5.2.1" **intransitive()**

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-assembly_2.10" % "1.3.0-cdh5.4.0" **intransitive()**
```

I understand that **intransitive()** is used to add dependencies just for compilation, and allowing the jars in jar_home to be used for execution. In place of  intransitive(), I have also used "compile" & "provided".. But the same exceptions are still thrown. I did some research, and sharding has been recommended-- assuming of course that it is a dependency conflict, but SBT 13x which I am using does no support a sharding strategy. The other is to is to modify my application to
depend on the same version of the third-party library that Spark does. I am certain that I have done that also.

So I am now out of options. Can you help me solve this?

Comment: I don't know about `intransitive()`, but I believe `"provided"` is required there. So you need `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0-cdh5.2.1" % "provided"`. I've never seen `spark-assembly` package as a dependency as well.

Comment: I have used provided as well as compiled. Perhaphs it's the spark assembly and spark code creating the conflict. I'll take assembly out and try again. Thanks

Comment: I didnt work, @mehmetminanc